# How can I display the search result entries on the search page in craft cms/ twig?

Tags: twig, octobercms, craftcms

This is my first Craft project. 
This project uses craft 2.
I am having trouble displaying the card/results of entries on the results page.
On the results page if I search for a person in the side bar I am shown eg "16 results found for julian. Reset filters"  but in the main section no cards are displayed and its completely empty.
I'm not sure how this really works so if someone could please take a moment to help me and explain how it works/why I'm not seeing results in the main section I would really appreciate it!
Thank you in advance

**NAVIGATION ON INDEX PAGE**

```
{% set group = group|default('global') %}
{% set scope = scope|default(craft.entries.limit(null)) %}
{% set people = craft.entries.section('People') %}
<nav class="sidenav">
<h3 data-target=".sidenav__content" class="sidenav__heading js-accordion-toggler">
All People
</h3>

<div class="sidenav__content is-hidden is-transparent">
    <ul>
        {% for entry in people %} {% set active = craft.request.path ~ '/' matches "|^#{people.uri}/|" %}
        <li class="sidenav__item {{ active ? 'sidenav__item--active' : '' }}">
            <a class="sidenav__link" href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <form class="js-search-form" action="{{ url('search/results') }}">
        <div class="sidenav__search">
            <input class="sidenav__input js-search-form-input" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search">
            <input type="hidden" name="s" value="{{ group }}">
            <button class="sidenav__submit js-search-form-trigger" type="submit"></button>
        </div>
    </form>
    {% if results is defined and query is defined %}
    <div class="sidenav__search-results">{{ results }} results found for {{ query }}.
        <a href="/{{ group }}">Reset filters</a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

**RESULTS PAGE**

```
    {% extends "_layouts/_master" %}

    {% set section = craft.request.getParam('s') %}
    {% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}

    {% if section == 'publications' %}
        {% set section_title = 'Publications' %}
        {% set params = {
            section: 'publications',
            with: [
                'publicationCategory',
                'publicationAuthor'
            ]
        } %}

    {% elseif section == 'news' %}
        {% set section_title = 'News & Events' %}
        {% set params = {
            section: 'news',
            with: [
                'newsCategory',
                'newsAuthor'
            ]
        } %}

    {% elseif section == 'People' %}
        {% set section_title = 'People' %}
    {% set params = {
            section: 'People',
            with: [
                'relatedPerson'
            ]
        } %}
    {% endif %}

    {% block meta %}
        {% do craft.sproutSeo.meta({
            default: 'evolution7MetaDefaults',
            title: section_title,
        }) %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% set results = craft.entries(params).search(query).order('score') %}
    {% set category = craft.categories.slug() %}

    {% paginate results.limit(10) as pageInfo, entriesOnPage %}

    {% block content %}
        {% include '_includes/hero-category' with {
            'title': section_title,
            'entry': category,
            'defaultHero' : defaultImages.heroBackground.first,
        } only %}

        {% spaceless %}
        <main class="page page--cols">
            <div class="grid grid--full grid--flex">
                <div class="grid__item lap-and-up-one-quarter">
                    {% include '_includes/sidenav' with { 'group': section, 'var': 'all', 'query': query, 'results': results|length } only %}
                </div>
                <div class="grid__item lap-and-up-three-quarters">
                    <div class="page__content page__content--list">
                        {% if results|length %}
                            <ul>
                                {% for entry in entriesOnPage %}
                                    {% if section == 'publications' %}
                                        {% include 'publications/_card' with { 'entry': entry } only %}
                                    {% elseif section == 'news' %}
                                        {% include 'news/_card' with { 'entry': entry } only %}
                                    {% elseif section == 'people' %}
                                        {% include 'people/_card' with { 'entry': entry } only %}
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% include '_includes/pagination' %}
                            </ul>
                        {% else %}
                            <p class="page__noresults">Your search for “{{ query }}” didn’t return any results.</p>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        {% endspaceless %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try once searching with pagination code:

```
{% set query = craft.app.request.getParam('search_query') %} 
    {% set all_query = craft.app.request.getParam('all_search') %} 
    {% if query is not empty %} 
        {% set allEntries = craft.entries.search(query).limit(10) %}
        {% paginate allEntries as entries %} 
        {% if entries|length %}
            <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">    
                <div class="searchresultsstatus">
                    <p>Showing <strong>{{ paginate.first }}</strong>–<strong>{{ paginate.last }}</strong> of <strong>{{ paginate.total }}
                    </strong> results for: <strong class="query">{{ query }}</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% for entry in entries %}
                    {# Show data in Loop #}
           {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```